# How to get all members / functions of a module?

Tags: reflection, metaprogramming, d

```
module testmodule;

struct testmodule {}

pragma(msg, __traits(allMembers, testmodule));
pragma(msg, __traits(allMembers, .testmodule));
```

Prints:

```
tuple()
tuple()
```

How do I do it when a declaration in the module has the name of the module?

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555329/d-finding-all-functions-with-certain-attribute/25560800#25560800

Comment: From your link:
It is liable to break if a module shares a name with a member, such as the example with main mentioned above. Work around by using unique module names with some package dots too, should be ok.



Which is the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No built-in mechanism for this disambugation is provided because usually compiler can figure it on its own and such necessity was simply not foreseen.

Here is a simple library utility that generalizes approach proposed by @rcorre (nice idea!):

```
module getmod;

struct getmod {};

template isModule(alias sym)        
{
    static if (is(typeof(sym) == function))
        enum isModule = false;
    else
    {
        import std.array : startsWith;
        enum isModule = sym.stringof.startsWith("module ");
    }
}

template Module(alias sym)
    if (isModule!sym)
{
    alias Module = sym;
}

template Module(alias sym)
    if (!isModule!sym)
{
    import std.typetuple : TT = TypeTuple;
    alias Module = TT!(__traits(parent, sym))[0];
}

pragma(msg, __traits(allMembers, Module!getmod));
// tuple("object", "getmod", "isModule", "Module", "main")
```

This is not as good as built-in symbol disamgutation but should be practical enough.

Comment: What's the `TT!(__traits(parent, sym))[0]` for? Is that a trick to let you alias to a __traits expression?

Comment: Actually, `isModule` fails if the conflicting declaration is `void getmod(int i) { }`. It seems like `sym.stringof` is interpreted as `sym().stringof:

Comment: "Is that a trick to let you alias to a __traits expression?" - yes. Grammar does not permit aliasing __traits directly but this is purely syntax limitation, passing it through template alias parameter workarounds it.

Comment: I have missed template constraint in first one, updated the answer now

Comment: Proper implementation should probably also support recursive traversal up the parents to find a module but that is bit out of the scope of proof-of-concept answer :)

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case where you know `testmodule` refers to a struct that is a child of the module `testmodule`, you can use:

```
pragma(msg, __traits(allMembers, __traits(parent, testmodule));
```

If you need to determine whether or not a symbol is actually a module, here's something I threw together quickly that *seems* to work:

```
template isModule(alias sym) {
  enum isModule = !__traits(compiles, sym.sizeof);
}

static assert(!isModule!testmodule);
static assert(isModule!(__traits(parent, testmodule)));
```

I'm basically guessing that anything other than a module will have a `sizeof` property, but I may be forgetting some other kind of non-module symbol which does not have `sizeof`.

Comment: "I may be forgetting some other kind of non-module symbol which does not have sizeof" variadic argument lists don't have those too. Also packages (which are treated differently from modules). Most reliable solution I know abuses stringof : http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/78b06fbbf180