# Getting all imported modules with traits

Tags: module, d, type-traits

Is there a way with traits to get all imported modules or some other way? As far as I can see "allMembers" will not include members imported.

What I want to achieve is to import all members from within imported modules, but it doesn't seem to be as easy as I thought. I can easily get the members I want if I specify the full modules imported, but not if I take the current module itself.

So my question is, is there a way in D to get the names of all modules that are imported, because that way I can create a dynamic way of using "allMembers" on the modules.

To demonstrate what I mean.

Let's say we have module a.

```
module a;

import b;
import c;

...

foreach (member; __traits(allMembers, a)) {
    // members of b and c will not come here ...
}
```

Even if the imports of b and c are public, then they won't come.

What I want to be able to do is retrieve them there anyway.

Comment: the imports of `b` and `c` won't be included in `allMembers`, but `b` and `c` themselves will. You could call `allMembers` on each module to get the imported modules if you can filter the members with some `isModule(alias symbol)` template (which I don't know how to write).

Comment: [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25560800/1435461) may help you out

Comment: In my case they're not included at all. I will see what I can come up with, but as of now these solutions do not make a difference to me. @rcorre, already tried that solution and it didn't make a different. What I want to avoid is typing out the module names all manual, because it'll be a lot of modules I have to do it on. Thanks though

Comment: Update to this, it seems to be an issue with packages only. It works when I do it from a module, but as soon as I do it from a package it breaks. Can anyone confirm if that's intended behavior or?

Comment: looking at that answer I linked, there is a note about it not working with packages at the end. I'm not sure what workaround there is.

Comment: Yeah there are currently two bug reports, but there seem to be no statuses on it since it's like two years+. Maybe if I get time I'll investigate it in the compiler.

Comment: @Bauss I've put together a [pull request](https://github.com/dlang/dmd/pull/5290) for a relevant feature, but it's been languishing while I wait for official approval.

Answer (score 0):

If you import into a structure, then `allMembers` should work work; example:

( https://dpaste.dzfl.pl/629ff05bdab0 )

```d
struct Packages {
    import std_meta = std.meta;
    import std_range = std.range;
    import std_range_interfaces = std.range.interfaces;
    import std_range_primitives = std.range.primitives;
    import std_traits = std.traits;
};

void main() {
    foreach (X; __traits(allMembers, Packages)) {
        pragma(msg, __traits(allMembers, __traits(getMember, Packages, X)));
    };
};
```

… with some caveats which I don't recall exactly right now.

If you also want the modules to be imported 'normally' you could generate string-mixins from a list of module names. There's probably a number of ways you could approach this. (I won't go into details unless someone specifically asks about it)

---

I used this technique to great effect in my [std-underscore](https://github.com/Cauterite/phobos-std_) hack, with some help from `__traits(compiles` and `__traits(getProtection`. So you might want to check that out if you plan on doing something similar.

It's actually not as flimsy as you'd expect. I use *std-underscore* in every project now.

Comment: But that requires you to still import every package manually. The thing is I have multiple nested packages so a package may import other packages. In which case this isn't very sufficient, unless it takes care of it. What I did though to battle this was scrap the whole package system and just go straight with modules that acts like packages

Comment: @Bauss unfortunately there seems to be some compiler bugs preventing recursive introspection of imports. For example, see: http://pastebin.com/EiJfnbZv — when `foo` is a module which publicly imports some other module, these two pairs of `pragma(msg` statements are printing different results when they *should* all be equivalent. So for now this is the best I can do.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm aware of all these workarounds, but they're all not so nice anyway. Which is why I brought this up, because I wanted to prevent even more hacky hacky. D is nice and all, but it's small bugs like these that makes it not worth it anyway, because it has all these cool features, they just don't work great, they only work kinda. I usually ends up writing tools for these kind of things and then I invoke them before compile-time, but it's all just a mess in the end with so many work arounds :p you get me? It's way better than it was when I first got to start using D some years ago