# D execute all tests in module even if one fails

Tags: unit-testing, d

I am trying to write own moduleUnitTester which will execute all tests in module even if one fails. default unit tester works like [this](http://dlang.org/library/core/runtime/runtime.module_unit_tester.html):

```
size_t failed = 0;
foreach (m; ModuleInfo) {
    if (m) {
        auto fp = m.unitTest;
        if (fp) {
            try {
                fp();
            }
            catch (Throwable e) {
                writeln(e);
                failed++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the fp() throws on first failure. 
I dont really like that, the m.unitTest returns void function which is a function that will execute all unit tests in a module. Is there any way to list these unit tests and iterate over each one? this does not work:

```
 foreach (m; ModuleInfo)
 {
   __traits(getUnitTests, m);
 }
```

That would let me grab all the unit tests and then iterate over them freely.
Says the 'm' is a variable not a module. I could not find any documentation what is 'ModuleInfo' actually I found this only by mistake...

Comment: so i know the answer i'm just too lazy to type it up... so ehre's the short version: ModuleInfo is not a module, it is a runtime object describing modules. It has a `unitTest` (note the capital T in Test) member which is a function pointer that contains the tests... but it contains ALL the module tests as one function. You cannot break it down that way. `__traits(getUnitTests)` DOES break it down, but needs a compile time module: `__traits(getUnitTests, mixin(__MODULE__))` will get you started, but the trick is looping over your whole project imports and that's the part I don't wanna type up.

Comment: :). This is what I expected. However, how does one can iterate over all modules in the project? Or maybe, how does one gets a compilation time list of all modules?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Is what you are thinking of similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555329/d-finding-all-functions-with-certain-attribute/25560800#25560800 ? Does this extract every module from whole project?

Comment: Yeah, that's one option. It doesn't do every module from the project though: local imports are invisible to it, and internal modules may be hidden behind libraries. Those aren't necessarily dealbreakers, but it isn't automatically everything. You might also do a mixin or something to each individual module you have to inject a custom test runner too, or use an external build tool to pass helper metadata to the program. Also see: https://github.com/atilaneves/unit-threaded a lib that does some magic (it uses the build tool metadata by default to find modules). Last way is to break down the func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since I wrote half the answer in the comments anyway, I guess I might as well write a bit more in here too.

There's a few options here: compile time and run time. The compile time ones give you access to UDAs and other broken down details per module, but don't do a good job giving you access to all the modules. You can try to walk the import graph, but local imports are not available to this method. You can use a build tool to list your modules, but this, of course, requires you to actually use a build tool with that feature (https://github.com/atilaneves/unit-threaded is a lib that does this with dub).

You can also pass a manual list of modules to your test runner, which is the most maintenance work, but might be nice flexibility.

But, I want to do it at runtime, like you have in the question, just with more detail. How? By doing some low-level pointer stuff! It sometimes still pays to be an old assembly language hacker :)

Behold the code with inline comments:

```
module q.test;

unittest {
        assert(0, "Test 1 failed");
}

unittest {
        assert(true);
}

 // module ctor to set our custom test runner instead of the default
shared static this() {
        import core.runtime;
        Runtime.moduleUnitTester = &myhack;
}

bool myhack() {

/*

OK, so here's the situation. The compiler will take each unittest block
and turn it into a function, then generate a function that calls each
of these functions in turn.

core.runtime does not give us access to the individual blocks... but DOES
give us the unitTest property on each module compiled in (so we catch them
all automatically, even with separate compilation, unlike with the CT
reflection cases) which is a pointer to the auto-generated function-calling
function.

The machine code for this looks something like this:

0000000000000000 <_D1q4test9__modtestFZv>:
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 8b ec                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   9 <_D1q4test9__modtestFZv+0x9>
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   e <_D1q4test9__modtestFZv+0xe>
   e:   5d                      pop    rbp
   f:   c3                      ret


The push and mov are setting up a stack frame, irrelevant here. It is the
calls we want: they give us pointers to the individual functions. Let's dive in.

*/

        bool overallSuccess = true;

        foreach(mod; ModuleInfo) {
                // ModuleInfo is a runtime object that gives info about each
                // module. One of those is the unitTest property, a pointer
                // to the function described above.
                if(mod.unitTest) {
                        // we don't want a function, we want raw bytes!
                        // time to cast to void* and start machine code
                        // hacking.
                        void* code = mod.unitTest();
                        version(X86_64) {
                                code += 4; // skip function prolog, that push/mov stuff.
                        } else version(X86) {
                                code += 3; // a bit shorter on 32 bit
                        } else static assert(0);

                        // Opcode 0xe8 is the 32-bit relative call,
                        // as long as we see those calls, keep working.
                        while(* cast(ubyte*) code == 0xe8) {
                                code++; // skip the opcode...
                                // ...which lands us on the relative offset, a 32 bit value
                                // (yes, it is 32 bit even on a 64 bit build.)
                                auto relative = *(cast(int*) code);

                                // the actual address is the next instruction add + the value,
                                // so code+4 is address of next instruction, then + relative gets
                                // us the actual function address.
                                void* address = (code + 4) + relative;
                                auto func = cast(void function()) address;

                                // and run it, in a try/catch so we can handle failures.
                                try {
                                        func();
                                        import std.stdio;
                                        writeln("**Test Block Success**");
                                } catch(Throwable t) {
                                        import std.stdio;
                                        writeln("**Failure: ", t.file, ":", t.line, " ", t.msg);
                                        overallSuccess = false;
                                }

                                // move to the next instruction
                                code += 4;
                        }
                }
        }

        // returning false means main is never run. When doing a
        // unit test build, a lot of us feel running main is just
        // silly regardless of test passing, so I will always return
        // false.

        // You might want to do something like C exit(1) on failure instead
        // so a script can detect that.
        return false && overallSuccess;
}
```

I'll leave pulling debug symbols out to print file+line info of succeeding test as an exercise for the reader, if desired.

I provide this filthy hack with the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT WARRANTY of any kind, not even merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.

I tested with dmd on Linux, it might or might not work elsewhere, I don't know if gdc and ldc generate the same function, or if their optimizations make a difference, etc.

I'd recommend using supported techniques like the build tool or manually maintained module list combined with compile time reflection if you really want a new test runner: that unit-threaded library does a lot of nifty things beyond this too, so do check it out.

But the runtime-only option isn't exactly a dead end either :)

Comment: Well, I have to say I honestly did not expect fiddling with bytes and stuff like that.:). Well thanks for writing this up! But I've decided to just go with two-pass using dub, and preBuildCommand - similarly as unit-threaded does this, also because I want to make use of UDAs. Its kinda weird for me that D seems to give you ability to fiddle with modules, but the list of all modules at compile time is not that easy to get. I am accepting your answer :), I will post my simplest solution I came up with thanks to you later.

Comment: Yeah, it is just because the list of all modules often isn't possible at compile time. Suppose you have a library that exposes `lib_interface.d` and it internally uses `lib_implementation.d` but that's hidden, compiled behind a `lib.a` file. The compiler knows the interface exists, but has no idea about the implementation - only the linker sees that. This is the same reason why you can get base classes at compile time, but a list of child classes can (at best!) be done at runtime, some third-party, dynamically loaded lib is also allowed to inherit from it independently of your original source.

Answer (score 0):

I said I'd post my simplest solution I come up with.. Well, unfortunatelly I was not able to achieve what I wanted with my solution, so after all I went and used [unit-threaded](https://github.com/atilaneves/unit-threaded). Approach that I wanted to do is:
using dub you can do a double-pass on your code, something like this:

```
    "configurations": [
    { "name": "executable" },
    {
        "name": "unittest",
        "targetType": "executable",
        "preBuildCommands": ["dub test -c gen_ut_main"],
        "sourceFiles": ["bin/generated_ut_main.d"],
    },
    {
        "name": "gen_ut_main",
        "targetType": "executable",
        "versions": ["GenUtMain"],
    }
]
```

this will cause 'dub test' it will first execute target gen_ut_main with Version set to GenUtMain. with that you can do something like this:

```
 version(GenUtMain) {
 void main() {
     writeln("gen ut main");
     generate_file();
}
```

generate_file can then genearete a new '.d' file, which will contain information about all modules. You can achieve it using either 'ModuleInfo' because ModuleInfo its fine to use runtime objects in generate_file function, or as unit-threaded did this you can simply iterate over filestructure in your project and get all .d files and then you have package list. The ModuleInfo has 1 caveat tho, it will give you list of ALL modules, which may not be what you want, wellits definitely not what you want because standard modules will have unit tests embedded so you will have to filter these out, I was not able to filter these out, and I decided to use the unit-threaded approach.

Now, after the target gen_ut_main will be done, the bin/generated_ut_main.d will be regenerated, which will be compiled by the unittest target. And this way you can run all your unittest by module, checking freely UDAs and with ability to run all unit tests in module even if one fails.

There is supposedly a package 'tested' which integrates with dub. Tested should give you a possibility to list all your modules, I was not able to make it work.

Comment: I think ModuleInfo's list of all modules will NOT include the unittests of separately-compiled library modules (it will only have those specifically passed to `dmd -unittest`, so you can compile some with tests that way, and the rest without. Phobos is built without. Though this might get muddy with some template-embedded tests.